# Reshaping list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, partitions

I have a list of square matrices $A_i$ as follows

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}A_1 & \ldots& A_n \\A_{n+1}&\ldots &A_{2n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A_{(k-1)n+1} & \ldots & A_{kn} \end{matrix}\right)
$$

and I would like to reorganise this matrix of matrices to the form of a list of matrices as the list of matrices

One way is to extract each row and append them to an empty list of course

$$
(A_1  \ldots A_n \;A_{n+1}\ldots A_{2n }\ldots A_{(k-1)n+1 } \ldots A_{kn} )$$

I'm assuming `Flatten`, `Catenate` and `Partition`  are another way forward

Comment: It looks like Flatten is all you need here

Comment: Just need to do something like `Flatten[a,1]`? where `a` is the matrix of matrices?

Comment: Yes that should work if it's structured how you described.